# COUNTING_SORT - Exam pseudocode algorithm and how it works

Tags: algorithm, sorting, pseudocode

I've bumped onto a certain algorithm which I cannot fully understand. Is it possible to have a section-by-section analysis together with someone?

Here it is :

---

```
 1. B <- new matrix (m)
 2. for i<- 1 to m
 3.    B[i] <- 0
 4. for j <- to n
 5.    B[A[j]] <= B[A[j]] + 1
 6. k <- 1, i <-1
 7. while i<= m
 8.    if B[i] = 0 then
 9.        i<- i + 1
 10.   else 
 11.       for j <-1 to B[i]
 12.           A[k]<-i
 13.           k <- k + 1
 14.       i<- i + 1
 15.return A
```

---

I understand most of the individual bits of it, but not its function. Line 5 is the most confusing one, as it uses a supposed A array (that we didn't define but we will gloss over that) to represent values inside the B array.

But I would greatly appreciate even a general explanation of it all, please.

Edit: For clarification, this is exactly how I was given the pseudocode. I have not altered or removed information.

Comment: This site is for answering specific questions. Please explain the parts that you do understand and what exactly you don't understand and properly format your code.

Comment: Line 12, `A[l]<-i` What is `l` (lower-case letter L)? I think this should be `A[k]`

Comment: @tobias_k looks like it should be a `k`.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing it out. I edited it now. Sorry, this was the first question I have ever made on this site. I was mainly looking for the name of the algorithm so I can look it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets compare it to [countingsort](http://opendatastructures.org/ods-cpp/11_2_Counting_Sort_Radix_So.html)

```
void countingSort(array<int> &a, int k) {
  array<int> c(k, 0);
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    c[a[i]]++;
  for (int i = 1; i < k; i++)
    c[i] += c[i-1];
  array<int> b(a.length);
  for (int i = a.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    b[--c[a[i]]] = a[i];
  a = b;
}
```

Your mystery line

```
for j <- to n
  B[A[j]] <= B[A[j]] + 1
```

Is simply the counting of occurrences of the values from 1 to `n`.

```
 6. k <- 1, // final position in array, 1-based
    i <-1   // iterator over count of values AND the value to store.
 7. while i<= m
 8.    if B[i] = 0 then
 9.        i<- i + 1 // there are no counted values so go to next value
 10.   else 
 11.       for j <-1 to B[i] // fill with B[i] with i
 12.           A[k]<-i // put target value into final position
 13.           k <- k + 1 // update final position
 14.       i<- i + 1
```

Only sorts values from 1 to `m`.

Comment: Thank you! This is the kind of answer I was hoping for. I expected it to be some pre-existing algorithm but I couldn't find which one. Also, the comments are MUCH appreciated, good sir.